# Interpreting forecast predictions of log transformed data

Tags: forecasting, back-transformation, logarithm

Using the forecast function in R, I make a 1-step prediction for a log-transformed data set Y,  ( Y = log(X) ). This prediction gives me a mean and a 95% prediction interval.

How valid is this prediction interval when considering the untransformed data? For example, the prediction may give a mean of 4 with prediction interval [3,5]. If we backtransform (with exp) this we get a mean of 54.6 with prediction interval [20.1, 148.4]. This seems to predict an exaggerated range of values over the predicted mean. Can someone explain this?

Further, if I wanted to draw from a probability distribution of my prediction, how should I do so?

Comment: Can you expand on why you find that surprising? The interval is width 2 on the log scale correspnding to a ratio of exp(2) on the original scale.

Comment: Note that the mean doesn’t backtransform like that.  E(log(x)) != log(E(x)).

Comment: @TheLaconic Nevertheless, it *is* valid to backtransform the prediction interval endpoints, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @whuber Agreed.  But it is an important point the OP seemed to have missed, so I thought it worth a comment.